# Replicating Facebook's button elements

Tags: css

I'm using Aristo's CSS3 buttons seen [here](http://socialistpear.com/journal/aristo-buttons-in-css3/). One thing I like about Facebook's buttons are the little sliver of grey between the border and background of blue button elements. To see this go to "Messages" then "New Message" .. the Send button has just a bit of grey to make it pop out. It looks like this is achieved with this bit of code:

```
background-position: 0px -17px;
```

I've put up my attempts on jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hHxh2/). My goal is to avoid creating a nested element if possible. I guess I could also create an image and set that as the background, but I was hoping this would possible just with CSS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could use the `outline` property for the border, and then you get to use the `border` property for the highlight.